# Bash oneliner to rename filenames

Tags: linux, bash, perl, file-rename

I often would like to easily rename a bunch of files. I always have to struggle with `find`, `grep`, `xargs` and `sed` to simply to the job. I would like to understand how I can do a better job using PCRE

Here my files:

```
$ find .
.
./08447.ctags
./10565.gitignore
./38037.inputrc
./42257.bashrc
./51395.gitk
./63705.gitconfig
./66352.octave_hist
./67049.ahk
./85869.vimrc
./89518.minttyrc
./desktop.ini
./dp4FontViewer64.exe
./SBZSwitcher_v1.8.9.7z
./xlive.rar
```

I would rename the dot files properly as I can do with this oneliner:

```
$ find . | grep -e '^[.]\/[0-9]\+[.]' | sed -r 's/^.*[.](\w+)$/\0 .\1/' | xargs -n2 mv
```

However I find this command very complicated and I am looking for something that I can easily use:

```
$ rename 's/^\.\/\d+\.(\w+)$/\1/' .
```

My alternative solution was to write this Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.010;
use File::Find;

die "Wrong regexp!" unless
    $ARGV[0] =~ m/^
        s(?<delimiter>\/|~|@|;|%|`|\|)
        (?<search>.*)
        (?&delimiter)
        (?<replace>.*)
        (?&delimiter)
        (?<flags>.*)$/x;

my $search = join('', map("(?$_)", split('', $+{flags}))).$+{search};
my $replace = '"'.$+{replace}.'"';
find(sub { rename($_, s/$search/$replace/ree) }, $ARGV[1]);
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: What's wron with the `rename` command line ?

Comment: By 'rename properly' what do you mean? What's the expected transform on the filenames? e.g. example result of that directory list?

Comment: @sputnick, I've never found any documentation about the `rename` command. Even `rename --help` or `man rename` are not very useful. Can I use PCRE with it?

Comment: @Sobrique By properly I mean 'easily'. A simple substitution line with some standard options such as '-r --recursive' etc.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/rename It's perl you know ?

Comment: @sputnick: It depends on the distribution. In some distributions, `rename` doesn't work with regular expressions.

Comment: Just need to add it earlier in $PATH or with debian likes, use `update-alternatives`

Comment: @sputnick And in my distrib it's a binary :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simple solution.

If your `rename` command is fine but you want it recursive, then :

[bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4)

```
shopt -s globstar
rename 's/^\.\/\d+\.(\w+)$/\1/' **
```

[find](/questions/tagged/find)

```
find -type f -exec rename 's/^\.\/\d+\.(\w+)$/\1/' {} +
```

[image: warning]
 **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`linux`)

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

and not containing `ELF`

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: Excellent, I always thought this f***ing rename tool was just absolutely useless. In fact I've never used the right tool. If Larry wrote it, it should match my expectations :) Thanks.